# How can I align the < signs in my array (piecewise function) in TeX?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, arrays

I don't know how to use `align` with an `array`, any suggestions? I'd like the first `<` sign in each line to match up while retaining the alignment that I currently have. Here is my code:

```
\be
\frac{M_{xB} (z)}{M_s} \sim
\label{piecewise}
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
0, & z<-b_{xB} \\
1+\frac{z}{b_{xB}},~ & -b_{xB}<z<0 \\
1-\frac{z}{b_{xB}}, & 0<z<b_{xB} \\
0, & b_{xB}<z \\
\end{array},
\right.
\ee
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd avoid unbalanced conditions, readers knows that they should look for the variable and the mixed right-left alignment is awkward.

There is an easy possibility for aligning the variables, that is, using interval notation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{piecewise}
\frac{M_{xB} (z)}{M_s} \sim
\begin{dcases}
0,                  & z\in(-\infty,-b_{xB}) \\
1+\frac{z}{b_{xB}}, & z\in(-b_{xB},0)       \\[.5ex]
1-\frac{z}{b_{xB}}, & z\in(0,b_{xB})        \\
0,                  & z\in(b_{xB},\infty)
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A few notes.

1. Avoid shorthands like `\be` and `\ee` that make the typescript more difficult to browse and work bad with editors trying to help you with colored syntax.
2. Place the `\label` in a more sensible way: between `\sim` and the brace is not the best position.
3. Load `mathtools` or, at least, `amsmath` that provide many facilities for typesetting mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly alternate suggestion, based on the conditions of `z`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \frac{M_{xB} (z)}{M_s} \sim
    \left\{
      \begin{array}{ll}
        0, & z<-b_{xB} \\
        1+\frac{z}{b_{xB}}, & -b_{xB}<z<0 \\
        1-\frac{z}{b_{xB}}, & 0<z<b_{xB} \\
        0, & b_{xB}<z \\
      \end{array},
    \right.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \frac{M_{xB} (z)}{M_s} \sim
    \left\{
      \begin{array}{@{}l  r @{} c @{} l}
        0, & & z & {}< -b_{xB} \\
        1+\frac{z}{b_{xB}}, & -b_{xB} \leq{} & z & {}< 0 \\
        1-\frac{z}{b_{xB}}, & 0 \leq{} & z & {}< b_{xB} \\
        0, & b_{xB} \leq{} & z\rlap{,} \\
      \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The above uses:

- `@{}` to remove any inter-column spacing (where needed)
- `{}` as a non-existent math atom to achieve appropriate spacing around binary operators/relations (like `<` or `\leq`)
- `\rlap` (`r`ight over`lap` or "zero-width box that is left-aligned") to remove any horizontal influence of `,`

Similar output to what is displayed last is obtained using [`empheq`](http://ctan.org/pkg/empheq):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\dfrac{M_{xB} (z)}{M_s} \sim \empheqlbrace]{equation}
    \begin{array}{@{}l  r @{} c @{} l}
      0, & & z & {}< -b_{xB} \\
      1+\frac{z}{b_{xB}}, & -b_{xB} \leq{} & z & {}< 0 \\
      1-\frac{z}{b_{xB}}, & 0 \leq{} & z & {}< b_{xB} \\
      0, & b_{xB} \leq{} & z\mathrlap{,} \\
    \end{array}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You'll note that I changed some of the `<` to `\leq`, since I thought the conditions should be continuous.

Answer (score 3):

A variant, with the `cases` and `alignedat` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackag{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \dfrac{M_{xB} (z)}{M_s} \sim\begin{cases}
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    & 0, & z & {}< -b_{xB} \\
    & 1+\frac{z}{b_{xB}}, &\quad -b_{xB} & <z<0 \\[0.5ex]
    & 1-\frac{z}{b_{xB}}, & 0 & <z<b_{xB}\\
    & 0, & b_{xB} & <z
  \end{alignedat}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `dcases` doesn't make a difference with respect to `cases`, because `alignedat` uses display style anyway. The first `z` is misaligned, though; `\hphantom{-b_{xB}<{}}` would help

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I changed `dcases` to `cases` (but left `mathtools` loading, as I think it's useful anyway). I don't understand your second suggestion: it  just increases the izontal space between the two groups of alignment. The difference in alignment between $z$ (or $0$) and the second line is only 0.6pt on my viewer. What an eagle eye!

Comment: I was referring to the condition in the top line, where `z` is not aligned with the others.

Comment: Oh! Yes, I deliberately found nicer to align the (left) `<` signs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses a single `dcases` environment (provided by the `mathtools` package) along with a couple of `\phantom` statements. If you prefer having the fractional terms to the right of the large curly brace typeset using smaller symbols, switch from `dcases` to `cases`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{$\phantom{-b_{xB}}$}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{piecewise-new}
\frac{M_{xB} (z)}{M_s} \sim
\begin{dcases}
0,                 & \phantom{-b_{xB}<{}}z<-b_{xB} \\
1+\frac{z}{b_{xB}},& -b_{xB}<z<0 \\
1-\frac{z}{b_{xB}},& \makebox[\mylen][r]{$0$}<z<b_{xB} \\
0,                 & \phantom{-}b_{xB}<z \\
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```